# Rails can't connect to MySQL even though Capistrano and MySQL Workbench can

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, passenger

I've just deployed my rails application, created the MySQL schema and copied over the database.yml via capistrano. I see the DB tables in MySQL Workbench (it logs via SSH tunnelling to my VPS host).

When I try to access my rails application via the web I am getting

```
Action Controller Exception: Mysql2::Error Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)
```

I am puzzled. The settings in database.yml are identical to those in the MySQL Workbench. If there were any problems with them Capistrano would not have been able to create the schema. I checked that the database.yml on the server has, indeed, been copied. It has also been correctly symlinked. What could be the problem? How can I debug this case? I checked the production log and there is nothing I can see that would explain this case. Can you give any advice?

Fyi: I am using nginx and passenger.

Comment: is MySQL listening on 127.0.0.1? Maybe you should try 'locahost' instead?

Comment: make sure of the environment you're trying to start, it could be for example that you uploaded the production db settings, but you are trying to start a development session, so it has no mysql configuration.

Answer (score 0):

@Mohammad AbuShady: you are right. This was the problem. Thank you! If you enter it as an answer I will accept it.

So the mystery was resolved - it seems that the rails application was running on my production server in development environment, not in production despite me deploying it using `cap production deploy`. I wrote a detailed blog post about it [here](http://feraldeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2014/12/cap-production-deploy-can-erroneously.html). The short story:

The problem is that the settings for the rails stack are somewhat messy. The environment can be set in multiple places. In this particular case the problem was, I believe, the following line in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

```
server {
    rack_env           development;
```

It, apparently, prevailed over the other places (e.g. deploy.rb) where I did set up the environment as "production".

The problem was that development settings in database.yml did not contain the correct database settings (they were supposed to work only on my laptop) thus it wasn't surprising that the application was having trouble establishing connection to MySQL.

In case someone stumbles upon the same problem I would recommend the following debugging strategy: invoke `rails console` in the root directory of your application on the production server (it would be something like `/home/deploy_user/my_app/current`) and run there `Rails.env`. It will show what environment the application is running in. Another way to check is to have a look at the log directory (e.g. `/home/deploy_user/my_app/shared/log`). In my case the file development.log had a much more recent timestamp than the file production.log. When I opened it I could clearly see the log of the HTTP request which produced the MySQL error (the time was the same and the IP address was that of my test machine). So it was clear that I was interrogating an application which was running in development mode.